# Does Laravel 6 disable observers in factories / tests?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

Ive just written an observer thats sends an e-mail whenever a user is created.

```
class UserObserver
{
    public function created(User $user)
    {
         Mail::to($user)->send(new UserAccountCreated(
            app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($user),
            $user
        ));
    }
}
```

I ran phpunit to test if my observer works, and it passed. However I was expecting to get an email for each time my tests create a user.

For example:

```
/** @test */
    public function an_admin_can_view_all_clients()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create(['is_admin' => true]);
        $client = factory(Client::class)->create();
        $client2 = factory(Client::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)->get(route('clients.index'))
            ->assertSuccessful()
            ->assertSee($client->name)
            ->assertSee($client2->name);
    }
```

I would expect an email to be sent when that factory creates the user. But I don't receive one in Mailtrap.

Just wondering if and where laravel disables my observer being triggered when my factory creates that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have to disable it yourself by using `Model::withoutEvents()`

For example:

```
$user = User::first();
User::withoutEvents(function () use ($user) {
    $user->delete();
});
```

Also in this specific case you can also use the [Mail fake system](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mocking#mail-fake) provided by Laravel itself

Comment: I don't have that line anywhere, and didn't receive any emails in mailtrap when I ran phpunit.

Comment: do you have a .env.testing file or a different .env file when you run your tests?

Comment: I only have one env. 
In phpunit.xml I set 'APP_ENV' to testing and make an sqlite in memory database.

Comment: What happen if you `dd` inside the `created` method during that specific test? Can you it it?

Comment: added dd("hello") to the observer.

phpunit --filter an_admin_can_view_all_clients

returns "hello"
No email in mailtrap

Comment: So the even is dispatched the problem is that something inside your testing configuration is preventing the mail to be sent out. I suggest to check if you have something like "mail.pretend" or different configuration for your testing environments.

Comment: Hmm, not that I can see. And even if it is there somewhere, I didn't write anything like that. So, must be in the core somewhere?

Comment: I've a lot of tests and if I switch my `env.testing` to mailtrap i get those emails so it's something on your codebase

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll look into it. Thanks.